# adding labels/captions with imagemagick

Tags: linux, command-line, imagemagick

I'm trying to make a script that will add the file name to a label under the images. I found out I can use ImageMagick on linux to do that, but I can't figure how to do it right.

The documentation gives this example:

`magick dragon.gif   -background Khaki  label:'Faerie Dragon' -gravity Center -append    anno_label.jpg`

The Text comes out on the left side on the image and written vertically. Changing it to `+append` moves in down, but the text is still written vertically.

When just creating a text image it seems to be writing it fine.

Also, for making the text bold do I have to use `pango:'<b>text</b>`? or is there another way?